# Proving existence of an encryption scheme that has indistinghuishable multiple encryptions in the presence of an eavesdropper, but is not CPA-secure

Tags: pseudo-random-function, chosen-plaintext-attack, multiple-encryption

I got stuck in trying to find a solution to the 3.7 exercise of the Katz-Lindell book. The exercise also assumes the existence of a pseudorandom function. The problem is that a multiple messages encryption scheme has to be non-deterministic in order to be indistinguishable. So how is it possible for such encryption scheme to be CPA vulnerable, if it's non-deterministic as we are considering a multiple messages scenario and a pseudorandom function involved in the Encryption-Decryption process?

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, from the answer, I don't understand how is it possible for the scheme to not necessarily be non-deterministic. Because, if I'm not mistaken, the encryption scheme in the multiple messages scenario has to be non-deterministic in order for the 2 vector ciphertexts C_0 and C_1 to be indistinguishable.